# Error on filling my 2D array in java from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, conways-game-of-life

I am attempting to create the Game of Life, but have hit a hard point early on. :(

I have a text file with "o" and "*" as the starting grid/matrix and my constructor has to read that file and fill a 2D array with it.

Problem is that I have an error where it says "sc.nextLine();", i'm not too sure what I am missing to fill in array.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

   public class LifeGrid {

   int x, y;

   public LifeGrid(int newy, int newx, String filename) {
   x = newx;
   y = newy;
   File file = new File(filename);
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
   int[][] board = new int[y][x];
   while (sc.hasNext())
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
          board[i][j] = sc.nextLine(); <- error here
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: you should post your code :)

Comment: Fix your indentation. Code should be easy to read if you are asking people to try and read it.

Comment: accidentally posted it before i added code, all should be good now :D

Comment: You should be a bit more precise in your code. E.g. `board` is an Integer-array - why `int`? `boolean` would be sufficient. How can "o" and "*" be transformed into the desired datatype (`int`)? And the board boundaries are part of the state. They should be read from the file as well.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
  {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
    {
      board[i][j] =  line.charAt(j)=='*'?1:0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does the line "line.charAt(j)=='*'?1:0;" do?

Comment: It takes the j'th character from the text line. Test lines are read from the file using Scanner "sc". The "?" operator is the inline "if". If character is '*', the output is "1", else (operator ":") it is "0".